# Flying Saucer doesn't apply inline CSS

Tags: java, html, css, flying-saucer

When I try to generate PDF using Flying Saucer the inline CSS is not applied and is printed in the generated PDF. Exact duplicate here:

[Flying Saucer is not applying internal css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231935/flying-saucer-is-not-applying-internal-css)

I have already put my CSS under `<head></head>` tag.

My code is below:

```
package org.xhtmlrenderer;

import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

/**
 * @author Parag.Joshi
 *
 */
public class HTMLToPDFFS {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        String inputFile = "C:\\test.html";
        String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
        String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(url);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);
        renderer.finishPDF();
        os.close();
    }

}
```

My HTML is below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Summary log
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">

body, html { border: 0px }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif }
body, p { font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif }
code { font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace }

body            { background-color: #FFFFEE; font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;}
p           { font-size: 11px; font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif; color: #040404; background-color: #FFFFEE; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 10px; }
h1          { font-size: 17px; color: #FFA500; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: #0000EE; padding-top:6px; padding-bottom:7px; padding-left:10px; }    
h2          { font-size: 15px; color: #0055AA; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 16px;  background-color:#FFCC66; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px; padding-left:10px; }
h3          { font-size: 15px; color: #660000; margin-bottom: 8px;  margin-top: 15px; }
h4          { font-size: 12px; color: black; margin-bottom: 8px;  margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 8px; font-style: normal; }
code        { font-size: 12px; margin-left: 16px; padding-left:16px} 
hr          { height: 0px; noshade: true; border: 1; width: 100%; }

/* FFCC66 FFEE99 */

.pError {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
 color: red;
 background-color: #FFFFEE;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.pSkipped_PrevTaskFailed {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
 color: #FF9D8B; /*Light red shade color*/
 background-color: #FFFFEE;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.pSkipped_DateNotInRange {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
 color:  #00BFFF; /*Light blue shade color*/
 background-color: #FFFFEE;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.pAbort {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
 color: #FFA500; /*Orange color*/
 background-color: #FFFFEE;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.pNeutral {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
 color: silver;
 background-color: #FFFFEE;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.pSummary {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
 color: blue;
 background-color: #FFFFEE;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.tableHead {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #0055AA;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 16px;
 background-color:#FFCC66;
 padding-top:0px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 /*padding-left:10px;*/
}
.tdPadding {
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-left:7px;
padding-right:7px;
}
.h2RowHead {
 background-color: #999999;
 color: #eeeeee;
 font-weight: bold
}

.tableContent {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: black;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 16px;
 background-color:#FFCC66;
 padding-top:0px;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 /* padding-left:10px; */
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="tableHead" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td align="left" class="tdPadding">
          Summary log
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td align="left" class="tdPadding">
          <b>User's account name: </b>First.Last
        </td>
        <td align="center" class="tdPadding">
          <b>Server: </b>myServer
        </td>
        <td align="right" class="tdPadding">
          <b>Execution date: </b>22.01.2015 04:49:37:918
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h2 class="h2RowHead">
      Running Process for [22.01.2015]
    </h2>
    <p>
      <b></b>
    </p>
    <h4>
      MAIN
    </h4>
    <hr />
    <p class="pError">
      (1) Task: <i>Task1</i> invoked at 22.01.2015
      04:49:37:934 >> <b>FAILURE!</b> Task finished with return code:
      13. Component: Task1 timed out.
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
      Record Statistics: Processed: 68680 | Filtered: 0 | Failed: 0 | Running
      time: 00:00:05
    </p>
    <hr />
    <p class="pError">
      (2) Task: <i>Task2</i> invoked at 22.01.2015 04:49:43:254 >>
      <b>FAILURE!</b> Task finished with return code: 4. Failed to load
      Component [Task2] from file "C:\Task2.txt". Reason: DataFlow now found.
    </p>
    <br />
    <p class="pError">
      (3) Task: <i>Task3</i> invoked at 22.01.2015 04:49:43:300 >>
      <b>FAILURE!</b> Reason: Current object state [Ready] doesn't
      allow to stop this component [Task3].
    </p>
    <br />
    <h2 class="h2RowHead">
      Process execution summary:
    </h2>
    <p>
      Active Tasks: 3<br />Executed Tasks: 3<br />Successful Tasks: 0<br />Failed
      Tasks: 3<br />Skipped Tasks based on calendar: 0<br />Skipped Tasks
      based on result of previous Task: 0<br /><b>Process completed
      successfully. Elapsed time: 5 seconds.</b>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** I am using Flying Saucer R8 (compiled with iText 2.1.7) as I was facing an issue mentioned here:

https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/issues/detail?id=126

Comment: So, what are you asking?

Comment: It prints CSS. How to get rid off that?

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: Sure, should have added that in the beginning. But edited the question now.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me with `flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.7` from maven central.

Comment: How can I achieve that? As I said I am using Flying Saucer (R8). Do I just need to add flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.7.jar to classpath? But even in that case CSS is still printed in PDF.

Comment: @AleksandrM: It would be great if you can help.

Comment: I don't see how. As I've already told you, your code works for me.

Comment: Did you use core-renderer.jar from version R8 and flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.7.jar?

Comment: @AleksandrM: I got it fixed. I guess there was version mismatch in my project. Thanks for your help. Can you please add this as an answer so that I can accept it? One more thing Flying Saucer version 9.0.7 is available at maven but seems that is not officially released yet?