# java itext embedded css

Tags: java, css, itext

my question could be a duplicate of this one ([Flying Saucer is not applying internal css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231935/flying-saucer-is-not-applying-internal-css)) but in this one I can't find an answer.
    I've an HTML that appears correct in browser but I try to convert to PDF I loose style.

```
I prefer to add comment to existing question but I can't.


My dependency:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
            <version>R8</version>
        </dependency>

My code:
try {
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocument(new File("c:\\Temp\\report\\spRPT_2002_SSBA2_CheckNotify.html"));
            renderer.layout();
            FileOutputStream osFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\Temp\\report\\spRPT_2002_SSBA2_CheckNotify.pdf"));
            renderer.createPDF(osFile);
            renderer.finishPDF();
            osFile.flush();
            osFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

PDF is created without style.
Thanks all
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please post your HTML as well. We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help you out.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how to add a file in stackoverflow

Comment: You don't need to attach a file, we need to see the code in the file. The HTML structure, the CSS, everything that is outlined in the post I linked to above. If we can't replicate your issue, it's really difficult to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I post my full HTML here:
http://sinedweb.sined.it/filemanager/download/free/spRPT_2002_SSBA2_CheckNotify.html

Comment: There are [several errors](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsinedweb.sined.it%2Ffilemanager%2Fdownload%2Ffree%2FspRPT_2002_SSBA2_CheckNotify.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) in your markup. As per the [iText FAQ](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-doesnt-css-and-rowspan-work), even the smallest error can cause iText to not properly apply CSS. Try fixing these errors and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check it as soon as possible.
Previously I use an ActiveX library with vb6 and works fine so I don't think it could be the problem.
I will update

Comment: Also: Flying Saucer isn't an iText product. It isn't endorsed by iText because it uses a version of iText that can't be used in a commercial context. The official way to convert HTML+CSS to PDF is iText 7 + the pdfHtml add-on. See the official tutorial on the official web site: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml

Comment: Hello, I've solved each problem of my HTML and now everything works fine.
Regarding iText7, it's a commercial product. Is there anything costs free that could be used in commercial solution?
Thanks for all,
Mirko